# How to update .htaccess in virtual host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Today I got a website from a UI developer. I changed all *.html code to the *.php. It runs well on local server. After posting it on online server, I gives

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

After googling it, what I learned is that I need to change the .htaccess file.
[Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file)

But I made my virtual host some days ago. I could not get

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Instead I got three files in /etc/apache2/sites-available/.

```
000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf  tangelotown.org.conf
```

The content of tangelotown.org.conf is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName tangelotown.org
    ServerAlias www.tangelotown.org

    ServerAdmin president@tangelotown.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tangelotown.org/public_html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This file does not contain

```
<Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
 </Directory>
```

as explained on the site. Please help me to solve this issue. My site is
[tangelotown.org](http://tangelotown.org/home.php)

Comment: Try asking this on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the Directory stanza just before the VirtualHost stanza, but you probably want to change the Directory

```
<Directory /var/www/tangelotown.org/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Comment: then what? will it work?

Comment: My apologies, put that stanza just before the virtualhost stanza in the apache conf file, restart apache and test..

Comment: Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 31 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/tangelotown.org.conf: Expected </VirtualHost> but saw </Directory>

Comment: after all these stuff getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: can you update the question with the new contents of tangelotown.org.conf ? and allso the apache error log?

Comment: @dbinnss66 thank you for the help. There was something wrong with php code.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer of the question is that it has php error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The above error shows that there is a problem with php code. I was using require_once("") and deleted the required file. Please check error log before considering such questions.

Comment: Logs are your friends... ;-)